# xstream - getting value of content between tag

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xstream

I am parsing xml using XStream. Suppose my xml is :

```
<result>
<obj1> ...obj1 structure.. </obj1>
<obj2> ...obj2 structure.. </obj2>
</result>
```

So, pojo classes can be made as :

```
@XStreamAlias("result")
class Result {
   @XStreamAlias("obj1")
   Obj1 obj1;

   @XStreamAlias("obj2")
   Obj2 obj2;

}
```

and it is parsing correctly. But problem is when xml changes to :

```
<result>Sorry error occured..</result>
```

I want to parse this xml in same class's field.

I tried following :

```
@XStreamAlias("result")
@XStreamConverter(value=ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings={"value"})
    class Result {
       @XStreamAlias("obj1")
       Obj1 obj1;

       @XStreamAlias("obj2")
       Obj2 obj2;

       String value;

    }
```

Though, it works in case of error response but in case of successful response I am getting null value in `obj1` and `obj2` objects. Is there any way to make a class that can work for both xmls?